Charging Li-ion cells
I have a Li-ion battery using 12 x 3.7 V 1500 mAh cells.
The cells are connected in 2 strings in parallel, with 6 cells in series in each string. 2P6S = 12 cells.
This gives a nominal battery voltage of 6 x 3.7V = 22.2V, and 3 Ah.

Q1: Can I charge this battery with a 24V, 1A power supply.
Q2: What is the required charging power?


Can you [edit] the question to clarify if you are using a charger designed for Li-Ion cells, or a power supply with a 24 V 1 A output.

2P6S would give you 3 Ah 22.2 V. 9 mAh is a very small capacity for a battery.

@ChesterGillon thanks i've edited the question

We get of questions about connecting batteries directly to power supplies. The answer always is, stop doing that immediately. Buy a charger.

Can an Adapter serve as a charger or is there still need for a charging board

(I finally have an idea where the 9 in the capacity you state for the connected cells came from - but if you look at 6 1.5 Ah cells in parallel, capacity would be 9 Ah, not mAh.)

@FrancisKosisochukwu No. An "adapter" or what other names there are for a generic power supply is never a charger. See my answer.


Q1: Can I charge this battery with a 24V, 1A power supply?

The answer is no.
You cannot charge batteries with a power supply.
You need a charging circuit between the batteries and the power supply.
Please note that if you connected batteries directly to a power supply without a charging circuit between them, you may have damaged the power supply or the batteries.
Please also note that damaged batteries are unsafe, mishandled batteries may explode or burst into fire, that may burn down a house and cause serious injuries or death, either way, insurance companies may not be too happy with your tinkering with batteries unsafely.
For Q2: The power of charging is a range between how long you want to wait, how much current the batteries are rated for, and how many charge-discharge cycles you expect before batteries are worn out. The charging current may also be limited by the BMS between charger and batteries how much current it can handle while still balancing the cells properly.

But I think it should be safe if you’re using a CC/CV source with the voltage set to a maximum of 4.2 * (number of batteries in series) and the current set to 1C. I’ve been charging my 21V battery bank at 0.25C with this setup for over a year now, and it’s been working well so far. And I did it for other batteries as well. I think that's what the charging circuits do.

@15Volts Of course, but CC/CV source is a charging circuit. It's just a very simple and requires human intervention to turn off the charging before battery damages from keeping it floating indefinitely at 4.2V. So it's not just a very good charger. But a power supply / adapter with 24V and 1A isn't a charger at all.

@Justme balance is an issue but 24 volts and six cells is 4 volts per cell so IF you did maintain balance then you would actually probably not harm them. Perhaps. If the power supply did not mind being overloaded and simply went into one amp current limiting moded at whatever voltage it could supply then it would act as a cc charger and if it topped out at a genuine 24 volts also as a CV float at below the (typically) crucial 4.2 V/cell . I absolutely don't recommend it but it might perhaps just even work. || Edited : current <-- concentrent

@RussellMcMahon A 24V power supply is not a charger. Connecting batteries with 23V to it will draw more than 1A current, shutting down the power supply. There needs to be a charging circuit between power supply and batteries, no matter how simple. Batteries are not to be directly connected to random power supplies.

@Justme Thanks. I'm aware of the technical issues, and the strong inadvisability, but also wanted to "cover the bases" rather than just saying no. || Re your " ...shutting down the power supply." --> Note my "Perhaps. If the power supply did not mind being overloaded and simply went into one amp current at whatever voltage it could supply then it would act as a cc charger ". || Note that the question proper is good. The mention of the 1A psu is a "footnote". || SO - I agree with you and/but what I said is also technically valid. I'll review my comment to see if it would benefit from changing.

@RussellMcMahon I also understand that some PSUs may work, maybe due to overcurrent/undervoltage shutdown and restarting many times per second, but that's not the intended usage scenario. They might just blow a fuse or damage too, as they are not intended to be back-fed from battery. So in a generic case it's a no, but I acknowledge that given some assumptions it might be a maybe. The question itself about the charging power is a bit odd, as you can charge as fast or slow you want, and batteries charged slowly last longer. The maximum rate being in the datasheet, which we don't have.

@Justme  I have very lightly edited your answer to make it still fully relevant to the question, which I have heavily edited. If you are unhappy with this minor change please discuss and it can be redressed to your satisfaction. || I consider the question useful - it had two parts which were marginally acceptable as a single question but as-was it was not readily 'saved'. I considered deleting the add on non question then realised that invalidated your answer so I restored it as "Q1".|| They had confused technical specs which I amended. They said 6S x 1500 mAh = 9Ah. I will try to answer Q2...

... which is useful to others AND address their 9Ah error. "Soon" :-). || Again - if unhappy with edit please advise. I changed "none" to "no" and identified the portiona answered as Q1.
